# UI Slider - Click Drag Issue in IE only

Tags: jquery-ui, internet-explorer, jquery-ui-slider

Has anyone encountered this rather odd issue with UI Slider in IE. It's a basic slider, with a customised image for the handle. In IE, when you click and drag the handle, it only increases the value by one step (as defined via the 'step' parameter). It won't let you carry on dragging to the next "step" unless you click again and then drag it again manually.

Works fine in every other browser - you can slide to any step with a single click and drag.

Ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but for posterity: I had this problem as well and upgrading to the latest version of jQuery UI resolved it.